# What is O'Brien's 'double strong' coffee?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode "Whispers" - O'Brien orders coffee "double strong, double sweet". The double sweet is relatively obvious. In-universe, what does 'double strong' mean? Is this coffee brewed/replicated with an extra dose of caffeine, or extra tannins, 50% less water, or double shots of espresso, other alien stimulants, etc...?

Comment: The replicator is simulating a coffee brewed with twice the normal amount of coffee grounds and twice the normal amount of sugar; http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Strong-Coffee

Comment: I hesitate to call this real-world science, but it **is** about real-world cooking, and given the answer and the discussion around the answer, I have to question whether this is in scope for this site.

Comment: it's a fair cop - modified to make clear in-universe

Comment: I'm tempted to post *What is Picard's 'tea, Earl Grey, hot'?*

Comment: @NKCampbell:   I'm not sure that adding "in universe" changes anything.   You're questioning whether there is something special in universe that the replicator is doing or adding, but it's just meant to be his preference with no sci-fi behind it.

Comment: ...so you have an answer that proves that opinion? That's the question - what is he ordering

Comment: @NKCampbell, If Machavity's answer counts as merely opinion then it shouldn't have 20 upvotes and you shouldn't have accepted it.   If it is *The Answer* then you should agree it's not in scope.

Comment: fair enough on accepting it - I'll retract and wait for your better answer (he says with tongue firmly in cheek) - there is nothing inherently wrong with the answer in my opinion. Just like if somebody truly asked 'what is earl grey' - if they had never heard of it. Just because the answer is 'there is no in-universe special meaning - here's what that phrase means' doesn't make it off-topic

Comment: @NKCampbell:   Yeah, just for the record, I don't really care that much; I guess I'm just feeling argumentative.   I agree the answer would be **accept**able if it just added, "There's no special meaning", like you said.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I love a good argument - even just for argument sake! :) I think you made valid points - I do want to make sure to keep things on topic. I've fussed about that on other questions myself so no worries at all.

Comment: @NKCampbell:   Are you so sure about the *double sweet*?    Maybe it means it's made with Risan Omega-6 Disaccharonium Cloyanide ?

Comment: I thought that was obvious @ThePopMachine ;)

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40026/in-whispers-is-obriens-coffee-order-significant

Comment: I did see that one and considered it closely for dupe-age before posting my question @ThePopMachine

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Double strong" means [it's been brewed twice](https://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/morning-coffee-not-strong-enough-do-instead-0163739/) (emphasis mine)

> Like a strong-tasting cup of joe, but want more caffeine out of it? Start double brewing your coffee.
>
> Though it sounds both simple and complex, double brewing your morning coffee doesn't require much beyond its name: **just send your coffee through another brew cycle for a double-strong cup of joe.**

It means a stronger taste and more caffeine, generally. There's nothing to suggest that O'Brien was ordering something different than this.

Comment: As if regular strength replicator coffee wasn't bad enough.

Comment: Unnecessary scientific note: doing this almost certainly won't make coffee that is literally double the strength, since the dissolved and suspended coffee compounds from the first brew will partly hinder the dissolving and suspending of an equal amount of those compounds the second time through. Although a replicator could merely fabricate an equal quantity of water with double the compounds, limited by saturation of any solutes.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine what "send your coffee through another brew cycle" could mean. If I'm using a coffee machine (electric or stove top) or an espresso machine that would leave residue in the water reservoir while achieving nothing. If I'm using a French press or aeropress I could wash it out, put in fresh grounds, heat my coffee in a pan and put it back in, but I can't imagine that doing much that wouldn't be achieved more easily by just putting in more grounds in the first place. Is there a way to make coffee that I've missed, where it would make sense to brew it twice?

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm used to see a coffe made with coffee instead of water when using a [moka pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_pot).

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I believe you from a scientific point of view. But from personal experience of drinking it, it is insanely stronger than regular coffee. Triple brew is undrinkable unless you make it >75% milk and <25% triple brew.

Comment: @Zachiel ah yes, I see, on reflection that would work, since the liquid doesn't all turn to steam and re-condense. It would also make sense to do it if you wanted really strong coffee, since there's a limit to how many grounds you can put in. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathaniel: Before there were coffee machines, you'd pour hot water into one of [these](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaffeefilter#/media/File:Kaffeefilter.jpg) (at least where I grew up). (Some[who? -- my grandma, for one] consider it superior even now, as you'd pour a gush at a time, not continuously as a coffee machine does, giving a "better" taste.) (Cannot comment, I don't drink coffee.) It should be obvious how "another brew cycle" would work for one of them. And I am a bit shocked that, apparently, people no longer know what the "coffee machine" actually automated...

Comment: @DevSolar thanks, yes, I should have thought of that too. Random fact: in Japan, where I live, it's also considered superior, and cafes that serve coffee made this way will often have a sign outside saying so.

Comment: @Nathaniel the filter machines that use a porous bag of ground coffee need a little effort to get anything other than very weak (and lukewarm) coffee out of. I've seen them in the US/Canada/Costa Rica and found that first the water needed to be heated once, then to go through again with the pouch weighted down so it didn't float.  Next the coffee needed to be poured into a temporary container and back into the filter basket for another pass -- thats the double brew.  Finally it tasted of something.

Comment: @DevSolar they're quite common in workplaces where a kettle or hot water urn is provided. I've got one for camping.

Answer (score 5):

From a practical standpoint, this is more likely to be (replicated) "red-eye" than actually brewed a second time (by drip, press, or other method).

What's a "red-eye"?  According to my local barista, it's a cup of coffee with a shot of espresso added.  No reheating to damage the original coffee, but approximately double the caffeine, and roughly double the other dissolved/suspended "coffee stuff".

Comment: I never came across _"red-eye"_ but when I worked as a barista, we could produce one (enough for one regular cup) or two (two regular cups or one large cup) shots of expresso, to become a latte, cappuccino etc.  A _"Double"_ would be two shots instead of the one in a regular cup.  Formalised in the menu as an _"extra shot"_.  So yes, twice as much coffee in the cup, and _"double"_ was indeed used to refer to this, informally, by both customers and staff.

Comment: Yep, my home machine does this, too -- I have inserts for the filter that hold enough grounds for a single or a double shot, and a larger drink calls for more espresso (I rarely did extra shots at home, but I could trick my machine into Americano if needed).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very strong reference (or pun) to the novel [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four), where the antagonist is also called O'Brien, a high-ranking member of the ruling totalitarian party, which has among its goals a [simplification of the English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak), in order to make expressing emotions more difficult. Among these reforms is the changing of the adjectives "good, better, the best" into things like "good, plusgood, doubleplusgood". So "double-something" in that context is nothing more than expressing a superlative adjective (the strongest coffee, or, at least, an extremely strong coffee).